# Describe the quotient space

Tags: general-topology

I am doing my topology homework about quotient space and am unsure about my answer. Could some one help me check them?

> Describe each of the following spaces: $(a)$ the cylinder with each of its boundary circles identified to a point; $(b)$ the torus with the subset consisting of a meridianal and a longitudinal circle identified to a point; $(c)$ $S^2$ with the equator identified to a point; $(d)$ $\mathbb{R}^2$ with each of the circles centered at the origin and of integer radius identified to a point.

My answer to $a,c,d$ are:

$(a)$ A vertical line segment; $(c)$ one $S^2$ stacked on top of another $S^2$; $(d)$ infinitely many balls stacked on top of each other.

Are my answers correct? Of problem $(b)$, I am not even sure about what the partition is. Does it give rise to two partitions of the torus, one of a meridianal and a longitudinal circle, and another of the other points? Or any equivalent class consist of a meridianal and a longitudinal circle? In either case, I am not sure how to approach this problem, could anyone give a hint?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For $(c)$, it is better to say "... we get the *wedge sum* of two spheres, $S^2\vee S^2$", rather than "stacked". But this is correct, otherwise.

I would disagree with the existing answer and say $(d)$ is incorrect. We could not possibly obtain the "balls" i.e. copies of $D^3$ since these are not locally homomeomorphic with $\Bbb R^2$. Maybe you were being imprecise and you just meant to say spheres, copies of $S^2$ (which look like balls from the outside). But this is not quite correct either (and again, better say *wedge sum* than "stacked" because stacked would suggest something different and incorrect in the instance of more than two objects; in a wedge sum, everything is joined at the *same* point, like a bouquet of circles rather than a long chain of circles).

For $(d)$, here is my hint to you. It is rigorous to say the quotient map $q:\Bbb R^2\twoheadrightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism on each annulus: $$\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:n^2<x^2+y^2<(n+1)^2\}$$For $n\in\Bbb N_0$. The exact nature of $X$ depends on whether or not you consider the circle of radius zero in your quotient, but leaving that aside the analysis is the same in both cases. Just think about what happens to the *closure* of one of these annuli, and consider what the quotient does. **The boundary circles are sent to the** *same* **point**, so you must account for that. It's ok to first collapse one circle, then the other one. Once you understand what happens to one of these annuli, you can combine all of these in a suitable way to obtain the whole space $X$.

For $(a)$, my hint to you is to think about just identifying the two boundary circles *with one another* and then afterwards collapsing this common circle to a point.

For $(b)$, it would really help if you knew the standard CW structure on the torus $S^1\times S^1$. If you don't know what that means, don't worry. By collapsing the meridional circle you will get one of the spaces we have already mentioned (!) and then you can look at this space and collapse the longitudinal circle to the same point. It is much easier to visualise if you take the innermost longitudinal circle, the one that winds around the central hole of the torus.

Comment: Hi,  thank you for your answer! For $(7b)$ I collapse a meridional circle and get a pinched torus, but I don't know how to then collapse the longitudinal circle.

Comment: @Coco The pinched torus is right (and should be your answer for part $(a)$ as well...) but I agree that collapsing a longitudinal arc on a pinched torus can be quite hard to visualise. But as I already hinted, it becomes much easier if you choose the innermost longitudinal arc! An alternative perspective could be to say, this quotient space is the same thing (why?) as the reduced suspension of a circle. Another perspective is the CW one I mentioned; there is a continuous surjection $I^2\to S^1\times S^1$ "attaching the $2$-cell" and its boundary is the union of the two circles.

Answer (score 0):

(a) is not a line segment. *Only* the two boundary circles have been contracted identified to points. The rest of the cylinder still looks exactly the same! In other words, if you remove these two points from the quotient space, you will be left with the original cylinder minus its boundary. A line segment does not have this property, so it cannot be homeomorphic to the quotient space you're looking for.

For (b), let $X$ be the union of the two circles. Then the partition you want has $X$ as one equivalence class, and every point of the torus which is not in $X$ is in its own (singleton) equivalence class. In other words, we take this subset $X$ and contract it to a point, but leave the rest of the torus unchanged.

For (c), yes! Nicely done.

For (d), also yes! Very nice.

Comment: Thank you! Then I think the quotient space of $(a)$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$. Of $(b)$, there are many meridianal and longitudinal circles of a torus, the ones we choose will not affect the quotient space right? I think if we identify a longitudinal circle then we get a double cone. If we identify a meridianal and longitudinal circle, do we get four cones with a common vertex?

Comment: @Coco four cones with a common vertex is not right, sorry.